# Need Help Creating Simplified Password

Tags: java

I'm making a simple program for class that adds prices of various items together.
 After it gives a total it asks for a password; when entered correctly it will (eventually) allow the user to see information regular users do not get to see. The problem I keep getting is it wont accept a password. It will say incorrect password every time, even when typed correctly. I am very much a beginner and would appreciate the help! Between the `boolean admin = false;` and the next set of code, I just have some formulas and System.out's. Decided they weren't important to add in.

```
boolean admin = false;

System.out.printf("Your total comes to %.2f", totalPrice);
kbd.nextLine();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Enter the password.");
String password = kbd.nextLine();
if (password.equals(admin)) {
    System.out.println("You are now logged in.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect Password.");
}
```

Comment: admin's a boolean -- how can a String equal a boolean?

Comment: Hello? Again, your question doesn't make sense -- please answer the question above, and tell us what behaviors you're expecting with this code and why.

Comment: I pretty much want admin to show the message "you are now logged in" once typed in, if a different word was entered, it will show "Incorrect Password." Currently no matter what I type in, it shows "Incorrect Password."

Comment: @CortlinGillis Is your correct password `admin`?

Comment: yes admin is supposed to be the correct password

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is wrong in `if` condition. You are checking equality of a `String` with  `boolean`.

Change your if condition like the following

`if (password.equals("admin"))`

Note : String values are always surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Whenever you want to write a string literal, surround the text with double quotes!**

In your code, `admin` refers to the value of the variable called `admin`, which is `false`. When you write `password.equals(admin)`, it is the equivalent of writing `password.equals(false)`. Hence, the if statement will always fail and the else clause is always executed.

From the comments, I saw that you want the password to be `admin`. So you should compare the `password` variable to an actual `String`:

```
if (password.equals("admin"))
```

IMO, you should extract the string `"admin"` as a constant:

```
final String PASSWORD = "admin";
```

then you can compare it like this:

```
if (password.equals(PASSWORD))
```

So every time you want to change your password, you change the constant!

Comment: In your answer `PASSWORD` is a String variable and you are surrounding that variable inside a double quotes.

Comment: @Ravikumar oh my bad! Fixed now!

Comment: @CortlinGillis if you think my answer answers your question please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark.